# how can I build a script to store a Channel, BSSID, and ESSID individually for each network around in an accessible way with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm currently working on a bash script project with kali Linux 2.0. 
My script basically scans for networks, and when it has found one, it should store its ESSID, BSSID and Channel together in some way. then it uses the BSSID, ESSID, and Channel in a command for each network.
I've made the best research I could to find how can I store those details for each network. I know this can be done by creating a database or a table, 
though my knowledge about them is very limited.
so I've tried to use grep and awk  -

```
`b=$(iwlist <interface> scan|grep Address|awk '{ print $5 }')
echo $b`
```

which outputted the bssids in the following order -

```
`xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`
```

and without filtering with grep and awk :

```
`wlan2 Scan completed : 
Cell 01 - Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
Channel:xx 
Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel xx) 
Quality=24/70 
Signal level=-86 dBm 
Encryption key:on 
ESSID:"xxxx" 
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s 
Mode:Master`
```

but it did not help me a lot.
instead of that I'd want it to be like this :

```
`bssid1=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
chan1=X
 bssid2=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
chan2=x
.
.
.
.`
```

and the number of those variables in the script will increase with the number of networks scanned.
my question is, how can I build a script to store a Channel, BSSID, and ESSID as a variable individually for each network around with bash?

Comment: where do you want to store it?

Comment: as a variable, this is my preferred way. if you have another way to offer Ill be glad to hear

Comment: If you store in a variable it will last only till the scrip finishes executing. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes. that's it exactly

Comment: in what way did that command not help?  What was the output of `iwlist` and what did your command give you, and what were you hoping for from it?

Comment: `iwlist` outputted information on all networks around, as it scans for them. my command filtered the output and gave me a list of the bssids only. I wasn't happy with it since I need the bssids in separate variables, and I also need the channels as variables. replacing `Address` in my command with `Channel` gave me the channels , but again, not in a correct, separate and usable form.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question so that it included the output of `iwlist` and the showed the example of what you would like the result of the command(s) to be

Comment: edited (: sorry for my English, its not my everyday language.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the output of `iwlist` properly - a bunch of `x`s is no use to man or beast!

Comment: @user195587 and when doing that edit please show `iwlist` output, not just after your `awk` prunes it to some output that you don't wnat

Comment: these are bssids, I wont write here the actual bssids from security reasons. will post full output soon

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be with bash arrays and a while loop.  Here's one way to do it:

```
declare -a bsids
declare -a channels
declare -a essids

ind=-1
while read line; do
    case $line in
        Cell*)
            ((ind++))
            bsids[$ind]=${line##* }
            ;;
        Channel*)
            channels[$ind]=${line##*:}
            ;;
        ESSID*)
            essids[$ind]=${line##*:}
            ;;
    esac
done < <(iwlist <iface> scan)
```

Then you'll have 3 arrays that you can access like

```
printf "BSID 1: %s\n" "${bsids[0]}"
printf "CHANNEL 1: %s\n" "${channels[0]}"
printf "ESSID 1: %s\n" "${essids[0]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For DD-WRT this worked for me:

curbssid=`wl -i eth1 status | grep 'BSSID' | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'`

Enclose in backwords apostrophes.
You may have to change eth1 to eth2 if using 5GHz interface.